# Add Tinymce into Laravel 8

Tags: rich-text-editor, laravel-8

I've been trying multiple solutions but none of them worked out for me. Maybe because I am using
newest version of Laravel. So this place is my last hope.

All of these code snippets are inside one blade file.

```
@section('stylesheets')

<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/[my-api-key]/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            menubar: false,
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

And inside the content section I have this very simple code, later I will add other features,
but I am not moving on until this works out.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">

        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post">
                @csrf

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="body" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Text</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>


    </div>
@endsection
```

I have opened account on their website, and I have api key. But it doesn't work.

Also if you know some rich text editor other than Tinymce, that works fine with laravel 8, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts are referring to wrong section, I moved everything inside content, and voila, it worked.